# Camino or Safari Cache Location

Tags: safari, browser-cache, minecraft, java-applet

I'd like to know where the default Java applet cache location is for either Safari or Camino on a Mac, because I'm trying to replace the minecraft.jar for classic with a survival test jar I got off the internet (I'd like to try that mode)

EDIT: For Camino, the string `browser.cache.disk.parent_directory` in about:config doesn't exist, and if I try to create it with a new location, nothing happens. Also, I can't find it in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Camino` or for Safari, `~/Library/Application\ Support/Safari`

Comment: are you unable to execute the jar from the command line?

Comment: It probably won't work because all other versions (including older ones) have other files accompanying them, and these could be found in the cached folder. All I would have to do is delete the old Classic minecraft.jar and replace it with the survival test minecraft.jar.